# Plot semilogx with matplotlib then convert it into Bokeh

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bokeh

I plot a figure containing several curves using matplotlib and then try to convert it into bokeh:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from bokeh import mpl
from bokeh.plotting import show, output_file


num_plots = 6
colormap = plt.cm.gist_ncar
time = np.random.random_sample((300, 6))
s_strain = np.random.random_sample((300, 6))

def time_s_strain_bokeh(num_plots, colormap, time, s_strain):

    plt.gca().set_color_cycle([colormap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 0.9, num_plots)])

    plt.figure(2)
    for i in range(0, num_plots):
        plt.plot(time[:,i], s_strain[:,i])
    plt.grid(True)

    # save it to bokeh
    output_file('anywhere.html')
    show(mpl.to_bokeh())    

time_s_strain_bokeh(num_plots, colormap, time, s_strain)
```

it works fine. However, I want to have a semilogx plot. When I change `plt.plot` in the "for" loop into `plt.semilogx`, I have the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'laxis' referenced before assignment
```

What can I do to change the x-axis onto log scale?

Comment: have you tried [`plt.gca().set_xscale('log')`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale)?

Comment: Yes I add this line after `plt.grid(True)` and I still get the same error.

Comment: Since Bokeh 12.5 (April 2017), [support for Matplotlib has been deprecated](https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/4/5/release-0-12-5/), so `mpl.to_bokeh()` is no longer available. Also see [this Github comment](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6249#issuecomment-299981362) by bryevdv.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with the same issue! 1/2 of the solution is this (supose my data is in a Pandas dataframe called pd):

```
pd.plot(x='my_x_variable', y='my_y_variable) 
p = mpl.to_bokeh()
p.x_mapper_type='log' # I found this property with p.properties_with_values()
show(p)
```

I edited this answare because I just found part 2/2 of the solution:

1. When I use just the code above, the plot is semilog (ok!), but the x axis is flipped (mirrored)!!!
2. The solution I found is explicitly redefine xlim:

   p.x_range.start=0.007 # supose pd['my_x_variable'] starts at 0.007
   p.x_range.end=0.17    # supose pd['my_x_variable'] ends at 0.17

With this my plot became identical with the matplotlib original plot. The final code looks like:

```
pd.plot(x='my_x_variable', y='my_y_variable) 
p = mpl.to_bokeh()
p.x_mapper_type='log' 
p.x_range.start= pd['my_x_variable'].iloc[1] # numpy start at 0, take care!
p.x_range.end= pd['my_x_variable'].iloc[-1]
show(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Bokeh `0.12`, partial and incomplete MPL compatibility is provided by the third party `mplexporter` library, which now appears to be unmaintained. Full (or at least, much more complete) MPL compat support will not happen until the MPL team implements [MEP 25](http://matplotlib.org/devel/MEP/MEP25.html). However, implementing MEP 25 is an MPL project task, and the timeline/schedule is entirely outside of the control of the Bokeh project.

The existing MPL compat based on `mplexporter` is provided "as-is" in case it is useful in the subset of simple situations that it currently works for. My suggestion is to use native Bokeh APIs directly for anything of even moderate complexity.

You can find an example of a semilog plot created using Bokeh APIs here:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#log-scale-axes

Comment: There are massive amounts of `matplotlib` code that I see/work with regularly.  I "hear" you that there is a matplotlib issue : but  "write it in native bokeh" is a capitulation not a solution.

Comment: Please consider this an invitation to contribute to make Bokeh's MPL compat better. There is currently more work to do than can humanly be accomplished by the core team, and more folks choosing to help is the *only remedy*.  As it is, MPL support is probably going to be deprecated and removed soon, unless a new maintainer steps forward. Is that a capitulation? I guess. I'm not going to apologize for only having the standard 24 hours in a day, or for "only" working 60 hour weeks to give away things to people for free. If Bokeh does not suit your needs you are welcome to use something that does.

Comment: No need to apologize - and please do call out that the feature may be deprecated. My point was to be *clear* on it.  I need to decide on how to support matplotlib.  `mpld3` is stalled.  It seems `bokeh` will not support it . I am going to upvote your answer now - since it gives ***a clear answer***. The fact that the answer were not the one I wanted? That does not change the *correctness *.  Now  - as to what to do to get some web enabled matplotlib support .. stil an open (but different!) question.

Comment: I appreciate your understanding, and I empathize with your frustrations. I do sincerely wish I had a better answer to give.